# HTML tabs support

Tags: html, css

Here's a website I'm making, when I select tab 4 (POKEMON#4) it does not deselect the previous tab and when I select a new tab tab 4 (POKEMON#4) does not deselect but the tab I selected initially does.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>

      <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <title>BAM Teambuilder</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/importable.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>

     <h1>Teambuilder<span>Build a Metagame!</span></h1>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
            <label for="tab3">Pokemon#3</label>
            <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
                <div>
            <br>
           <form action="#">
        <p>
            <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <label class="label">&nbsp&nbsp&nbspPokemon</label>
            <select id="bammon3">
                <option>Please select a pokemon</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>1) Simorgh</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>2) --</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>3) Flytrap</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>4) Name Needed</option> 
                    <option pokemon3=''>5) Pandoze </option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>6) Apaflite </option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>7) Dendurus</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>8) Bandirto</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>9) --</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>10) Tiflectum</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>11) Sinder</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>12) --</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>13) Springfest</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>14) Mirrage</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>15) Skulprit</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>16) --</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>17) --</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>18) Swelter</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>19) Tundear </option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>20) Slimurk </option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>21) Sluborac</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>22) Ogre </option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>23) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>24) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>25) Cychill </option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>26) Cydnidie</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>27) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>28) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>29) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon3=''>30) Farenheat </option>

            </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="label">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspItem</label>
            <select id="Item3">
                <option>Please select a Item</option>
                    <option item3=''>Apicot Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Aspear Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Bulletproof Vest</option>
                    <option item3=''>Assault Vest</option>
                    <option item3=''>Cheri Berry</option> 
                    <option item3=''>Chesto Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Choice Band </option>
                    <option item3=''>Choice Jacket </option>
                    <option item3=''>Choice Scarf</option>
                    <option item3=''>Choice Specs</option>
                    <option item3=''>Choice Vest </option>
                    <option item3=''>Chumchu Berry </option>
                    <option item3=''>Clear Lense </option>
                    <option item3=''>Enchanted Gloves </option>
                    <option item3=''>Enchanted Slippers</option>
                    <option item3=''>Focus Lens</option>
                    <option item3=''>Ganlon Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Jakt Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Lai Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Leftovers</option>
                    <option item3=''>Leichi Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Lenses</option>
                    <option item3=''>Lum Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Mental Herb</option>
                    <option item3=''>Millstone</option>
                    <option item3=''>Music Box</option>
                    <option item3=''>Noni Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Pecha Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Petaya</option>
                    <option item3=''>Racing Shoes</option>
                    <option item3=''>Rasin Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Rawst Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Salac Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Simorgite</option>
                    <option item3=''>Flytrapite</option>
                    <option item3=''>Sitrus Berry</option>
                    <option item3=''>Traveller's Boots</option>
                    <option item3=''>Zeppelin</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            <label class="label">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspAbility</label>
            <select id="Ability3">
                <option>Please select a Ability</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Enchanted Ivy</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Planting Roots</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Amplify</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Berserk</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Dauntless</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Disruption</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Endurance</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Jagged Hide</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Kleptomaniac</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Mystic Mirror</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Mystic Veil</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Resolve</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Spook</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Pain Eater</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Specialist</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Quick Blows </option>
                    <option ability3=''>Troll</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Head Start</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Build Up</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Muddy Armor</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Tactician</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Forge</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Disruption</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Overdrive</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Tough Scales</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Relentless</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Fire Proof</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Freezing Point</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Boiling Point</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Strong Tail</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Upgraded </option>
                    <option ability3=''>Sharp Eye</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Mystic Veil</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Sharp Shooter</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Mastery</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Contamination</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Superweak Armor </option>
                    <option ability3=''>eutrality Barrier</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Juggernaut </option>
                    <option ability3=''>Immune Defense </option>
                    <option ability3=''>Feedbacy</option>
                    <option ability3=''>Ghoulify </option>
                    <option ability3=''>Super Slams</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <td>
            <label class="label">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspMoves</label>
            <select id="Move9">
                <option>Please select a Move</option>
                    <option>Move 1</option>
                    <option>Move 2</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <select id="Move10">
                <option>Please select a Move</option>
                    <option>Move 1</option>
                    <option>Move 2</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <select id="Move11">
                <option>Please select a Move</option>
                    <option>Move 1</option>
                    <option>Move 2</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <select id="Move12">
                <option>Please select a Move</option>
                    <option>Move 1</option>
                    <option>Move 2</option>
            </select>
            </td>
                </tr>

        </form>
        <tr>
        First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <form>
            </div> 
            </p>
        </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
            <label for="tab4">Pokemon#4</label>
            <div id="tab-content5" class="tab-content">
              <div>
            <br>
           <form action="#">
        <p>
            <label class="label">Team Member #4</label>
            <select class="turnintodropdown">
                <option>Please select a pokemon</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>1) Simorgh</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>2) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>3) Flytrap</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>4) Name Needed</option> 
                    <option pokemon4=''>5) Pandoze </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>6) Apaflite </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>7) Dendurus</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>8) Bandirto</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>9) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>10) Tiflectum</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>11) Sinder</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>12) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>13) Springfest</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>14) Mirrage</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>15) Skulprit</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>16) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>18) Swelter</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>19) Tundear </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>20) Slimurk </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>21) Sluborac</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>22) Ogre </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>23) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>24) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>26) Cydnidie</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>27) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>28) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>29) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>30) Farenheat </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>32) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>33) Spychic </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>34) Murdoom </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>35) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>37) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>38) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>39) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>40) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>41) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>42) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>43) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>44) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>45) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>46) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>47) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>48) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>49) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>50) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>51) Charidbyss </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>52) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>53) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>55) Faeum </option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>56) Wyvearn</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>57) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>58) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>59) --</option>
                    <option pokemon4=''>60) --</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </form>
            </div> 
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5" />
            <label for="tab5">Pokemon#5</label>
            <div id="tab-content5" class="tab-content">
              <div>
            <br>
           <form action="#">
        <p>
            <label class="label">Team Member #5</label>
            <select class="turnintodropdown">
                <option>Please select a pokemon</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>1) Simorgh</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>2) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>3) Flytrap</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>4) Name Needed</option> 
                    <option pokemon5=''>5) Pandoze </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>6) Apaflite </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>7) Dendurus</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>8) Bandirto</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>9) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>10) Tiflectum</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>11) Sinder</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>12) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>13) Springfest</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>14) Mirrage</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>15) Skulprit</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>17) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>18) Swelter</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>19) Tundear </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>20) Slimurk </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>21) Sluborac</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>22) Ogre </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>23) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>24) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>25) Cychill </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>27) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>28) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>29) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>31) Celsice</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>32) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>33) Spychic </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>34) Murdoom </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>35) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>36) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>37) Name Needed</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>38) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>39) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>40) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>41) Name Needed </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>42) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>43) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>44) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>45) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>46) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>47) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>48) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>49) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>50) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>51) Charidbyss </option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>53) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>54) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>56) Wyvearn</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>57) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>58) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>59) --</option>
                    <option pokemon5=''>60) --</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </form>
        </div> 
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>

    <br style="clear: both;" />
    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: #fff;
  background: #9b59b6;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 100px 10px;
}
h1 span {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.tabs {
  width: 1500 px;
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.tabs li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
.tabs label {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 21px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #8e44ad;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.tabs label:hover {
  background: #703688;
}
.tabs .tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
  background: #612e76;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: #612e76;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
  display: block;
}

p.link {
  clear: both;
  margin: 380px 0 0 15px;
}
p.link a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #612e76;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
p.link a:hover {
  background-color: #522764;
}
```

Comment: On a more serious note, can you narrow down your code to your specific problem, please?

Comment: I removed some of the tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many wrong mistaken tags in your html, I got fixes some but don't create radio in different form :

```
 <h1>Teambuilder<span>Build a Metagame!</span></h1>
       <form action="#">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
    <label for="tab3">Pokemon#3</label>
    <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
        <div>
    <br>
<p>
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <label class="label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pokemon</label>
    <select id="bammon3">
        <option>Please select a pokemon</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>1) Simorgh</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>2) --</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>3) Flytrap</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>4) Name Needed</option> 
            <option pokemon3=''>5) Pandoze </option>
            <option pokemon3=''>6) Apaflite </option>
            <option pokemon3=''>7) Dendurus</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>8) Bandirto</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>9) --</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>10) Tiflectum</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>11) Sinder</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>12) --</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>13) Springfest</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>14) Mirrage</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>15) Skulprit</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>16) --</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>17) --</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>18) Swelter</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>19) Tundear </option>
            <option pokemon3=''>20) Slimurk </option>
            <option pokemon3=''>21) Sluborac</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>22) Ogre </option>
            <option pokemon3=''>23) Name Needed</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>24) Name Needed</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>25) Cychill </option>
            <option pokemon3=''>26) Cydnidie</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>27) Name Needed</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>28) Name Needed</option>
            <option pokemon3=''>29) Name Needed </option>
            <option pokemon3=''>30) Farenheat </option>

    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item</label>
    <select id="Item3">
        <option>Please select a Item</option>
            <option item3=''>Apicot Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Aspear Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Bulletproof Vest</option>
            <option item3=''>Assault Vest</option>
            <option item3=''>Cheri Berry</option> 
            <option item3=''>Chesto Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Choice Band </option>
            <option item3=''>Choice Jacket </option>
            <option item3=''>Choice Scarf</option>
            <option item3=''>Choice Specs</option>
            <option item3=''>Choice Vest </option>
            <option item3=''>Chumchu Berry </option>
            <option item3=''>Clear Lense </option>
            <option item3=''>Enchanted Gloves </option>
            <option item3=''>Enchanted Slippers</option>
            <option item3=''>Focus Lens</option>
            <option item3=''>Ganlon Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Jakt Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Lai Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Leftovers</option>
            <option item3=''>Leichi Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Lenses</option>
            <option item3=''>Lum Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Mental Herb</option>
            <option item3=''>Millstone</option>
            <option item3=''>Music Box</option>
            <option item3=''>Noni Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Pecha Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Petaya</option>
            <option item3=''>Racing Shoes</option>
            <option item3=''>Rasin Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Rawst Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Salac Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Simorgite</option>
            <option item3=''>Flytrapite</option>
            <option item3=''>Sitrus Berry</option>
            <option item3=''>Traveller's Boots</option>
            <option item3=''>Zeppelin</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <label class="label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ability</label>
    <select id="Ability3">
        <option>Please select a Ability</option>
            <option ability3=''>Enchanted Ivy</option>
            <option ability3=''>Planting Roots</option>
            <option ability3=''>Amplify</option>
            <option ability3=''>Berserk</option>
            <option ability3=''>Dauntless</option>
            <option ability3=''>Disruption</option>
            <option ability3=''>Endurance</option>
            <option ability3=''>Jagged Hide</option>
            <option ability3=''>Kleptomaniac</option>
            <option ability3=''>Mystic Mirror</option>
            <option ability3=''>Mystic Veil</option>
            <option ability3=''>Resolve</option>
            <option ability3=''>Spook</option>
            <option ability3=''>Pain Eater</option>
            <option ability3=''>Specialist</option>
            <option ability3=''>Quick Blows </option>
            <option ability3=''>Troll</option>
            <option ability3=''>Head Start</option>
            <option ability3=''>Build Up</option>
            <option ability3=''>Muddy Armor</option>
            <option ability3=''>Tactician</option>
            <option ability3=''>Forge</option>
            <option ability3=''>Disruption</option>
            <option ability3=''>Overdrive</option>
            <option ability3=''>Tough Scales</option>
            <option ability3=''>Relentless</option>
            <option ability3=''>Fire Proof</option>
            <option ability3=''>Freezing Point</option>
            <option ability3=''>Boiling Point</option>
            <option ability3=''>Strong Tail</option>
            <option ability3=''>Upgraded </option>
            <option ability3=''>Sharp Eye</option>
            <option ability3=''>Mystic Veil</option>
            <option ability3=''>Sharp Shooter</option>
            <option ability3=''>Mastery</option>
            <option ability3=''>Contamination</option>
            <option ability3=''>Superweak Armor </option>
            <option ability3=''>eutrality Barrier</option>
            <option ability3=''>Juggernaut </option>
            <option ability3=''>Immune Defense </option>
            <option ability3=''>Feedbacy</option>
            <option ability3=''>Ghoulify </option>
            <option ability3=''>Super Slams</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <td>
    <label class="label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Moves</label>
    <select id="Move9">
        <option>Please select a Move</option>
            <option>Move 1</option>
            <option>Move 2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select id="Move10">
        <option>Please select a Move</option>
            <option>Move 1</option>
            <option>Move 2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select id="Move11">
        <option>Please select a Move</option>
            <option>Move 1</option>
            <option>Move 2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select id="Move12">
        <option>Please select a Move</option>
            <option>Move 1</option>
            <option>Move 2</option>
    </select>
<tr>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<form>

<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
    <label for="tab4">Pokemon#4</label>
    <div id="tab-content5" class="tab-content">
      <div>
    <br>
   <form action="#">
<p>
    <label class="label">Team Member #4</label>
    <select class="turnintodropdown">
        <option>Please select a pokemon</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>1) Simorgh</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>2) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>3) Flytrap</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>4) Name Needed</option> 
            <option pokemon4=''>5) Pandoze </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>6) Apaflite </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>7) Dendurus</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>8) Bandirto</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>9) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>10) Tiflectum</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>11) Sinder</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>12) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>13) Springfest</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>14) Mirrage</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>15) Skulprit</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>16) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>18) Swelter</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>19) Tundear </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>20) Slimurk </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>21) Sluborac</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>22) Ogre </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>23) Name Needed</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>24) Name Needed</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>26) Cydnidie</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>27) Name Needed</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>28) Name Needed</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>29) Name Needed </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>30) Farenheat </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>32) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>33) Spychic </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>34) Murdoom </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>35) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>37) Name Needed</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>38) Name Needed </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>39) Name Needed </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>40) Name Needed </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>41) Name Needed </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>42) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>43) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>44) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>45) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>46) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>47) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>48) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>49) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>50) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>51) Charidbyss </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>52) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>53) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>55) Faeum </option>
            <option pokemon4=''>56) Wyvearn</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>57) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>58) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>59) --</option>
            <option pokemon4=''>60) --</option>
    </select>
</p>
</form>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5" />
        <label for="tab5">Pokemon#5</label>
        <div id="tab-content5" class="tab-content">
          <div>
        <br>
       <form action="#">
    <p>
        <label class="label">Team Member #5</label>
        <select class="turnintodropdown">
            <option>Please select a pokemon</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>1) Simorgh</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>2) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>3) Flytrap</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>4) Name Needed</option> 
                <option pokemon5=''>5) Pandoze </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>6) Apaflite </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>7) Dendurus</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>8) Bandirto</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>9) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>10) Tiflectum</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>11) Sinder</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>12) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>13) Springfest</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>14) Mirrage</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>15) Skulprit</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>17) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>18) Swelter</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>19) Tundear </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>20) Slimurk </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>21) Sluborac</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>22) Ogre </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>23) Name Needed</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>24) Name Needed</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>25) Cychill </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>27) Name Needed</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>28) Name Needed</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>29) Name Needed </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>31) Celsice</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>32) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>33) Spychic </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>34) Murdoom </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>35) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>36) Name Needed </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>37) Name Needed</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>38) Name Needed </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>39) Name Needed </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>40) Name Needed </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>41) Name Needed </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>42) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>43) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>44) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>45) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>46) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>47) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>48) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>49) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>50) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>51) Charidbyss </option>
                <option pokemon5=''>53) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>54) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>56) Wyvearn</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>57) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>58) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>59) --</option>
                <option pokemon5=''>60) --</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>

<br style="clear: both;" />
```

This is inside `<body> ... </body>`. Make sure you have closing tags `</ tags>` in required tags. Please learn more about html tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have a LOT of mismatched tags.

Go through your HTML and make sure that all the tags are in the right order. If you write `<form><table>`, you MUST have `</table></form>` and not the other way around.

The radio buttons are not recognised as belonging to the same set because of your broken tags. Fixing them made the radio buttons work as expected.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try it, this is my first time making a website btw.